# QTreeView: How to check children after checking parent

Tags: c++, qt, qtreeview

I'm writing an application with QtCreator and am trying to check the children of a checked parent but can't seem to be able to find the correct way to do it.

I setup the model this way:

```
MyClass::MyClass()
{
    QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout;

    setWindowTitle(tr("Menu"));
    m_model = new QStandardItemModel (this);

    addItems(m_model);

    m_view = new QTreeView;
    m_view->header()->hide();
    m_view->setModel(m_model);
    m_view->setContextMenuPolicy(Qt::CustomContextMenu);

    layout->addWidget(m_view);
    layout->setMargin(0);
    setLayout(layout);

    connect(m_view, SIGNAL(customContextMenuRequested(QPoint)),
             this, SLOT(contextMenuRequested(QPoint)));
}
```

I have tried with the signal clicked() and a custom slot but can't figure out how to check the children of the checked parent.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to run setChecked on all the children.

Comment: That's not really what i meant. I know how to check an individual box, what i don't know is how to do it to all the children having checked their parent.

Comment: Ok. I have myself not used QtCreator as I code manually. I use a TreeItem class with a method setChecked that also includes the children.

Comment: I don't know if QTreeWidgetItemIterator could help you iterate over the tree items, check if the current item's parent is the clicked one and check it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement a slot for the clicked signal of your `QTreeView` and make sure to set the itens you want checkable in your `addItens` function using `QStandardItem::setCheckable`.

```
void MyClass::on_treeView_clicked(const QModelIndex &index) {
    QStandardItem* l_itemClicked = m_model->itemFromIndex(index);

    if (!l_itemClicked->rowCount()) return; // clicked item has no children

    for (int i = 0 ; i < l_itemClicked->rowCount() ; ++i) {
        QStandardItem* l_child = l_itemClicked->child(i);
        bool l_isChecked = l_child->checkState() == Qt::Checked;

        if (l_child->isCheckable())
            l_child->setCheckState(l_isChecked ? Qt::Unchecked : Qt::Checked);
    }
}
```

Comment: At least doing this with PySide, this only works if you actually click on the item, not if you check it in another way, like pressing space.